How to resolve error code 500 for TikTok research API
I am encountering issues with the TikTok research API while requesting videos and video comments. Despite using the same code, I only receive a successful response (code 200) once in about 20-30 attempts; the remaining attempts result in a code 500 (internal error). Additionally, after receiving a couple of successful responses (around 10 successful requests), I experience prolonged periods of the 500 error, sometimes lasting an entire morning or day.
According to TikTok's documentation, a 500 error -- "This is the generic error code for TikTok internal errors. Please refer to the error message for details and notify TikTok support."
Here are the activities I have tried to debug:

I've verified that my credentials are correct.
I'm not exceeding the daily quota.
I've also ensured my requests are error-free (I do receive a code 200 using the request code, but consistently get error code 500 with the same code).
I tried to change the request options, like max_count as 10, 20, 50, 80, 90, 100 (max is 100). It seems there is a higher likelihood getting code 200 when using max_count as 10, but at the end I am still getting code 500 after several attempts.
I tried using the VCE option provided by TikTok's research API, logging in with my credentials, but I keep encountering a "500: Internal Server Error."
I've searched online and found two posts (here and here) from a month ago indicating the same issue, but it remains unclear if a solution has been shared since then.
I've also emailed the research API team but haven't received any feedback yet.

My hypothesis is that TikTok may be updating functions for the research API internally but has not yet updated the guidelines on their website for API users. Despite numerous attempts, I haven't been able to deduce any consistent rules from the responses I've received (though I hope I'm mistaken, as that would imply a quicker resolution to this issue).
This problem is causing delays in my dissertation project, so I would be extremely grateful if anyone familiar with this issue or potential solutions could offer their insights.
The code I use:
fields = 'id,video_description,create_time,region_code,share_count,view_count,like_count,comment_count,music_id,hashtag_names,username,effect_ids,playlist_id,voice_to_text'
SearchUrl = f'https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/research/video/query/?fields={fields}'
Header = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(bearer_token),
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

start_date = '20231003'
end_date = '20231003'
m_c = 100
json_data0 = {
    'query': {
        'and': [
            {
                'operation': 'EQ',
                'field_name': 'hashtag_name',
                'field_values': ['KEYWORDS'],
            },
            {
                'operation': 'EQ',
                'field_name': 'region_code',
                'field_values': ['US'],
            },
            {
                'operation': 'EQ',
                'field_name': 'keyword',
                'field_values': ['KEYWORDS'],
            },
        ],
    },
    'max_count': m_c,
    'cursor': 0,
    'start_date': start_date,
    'end_date': end_date,
}

response = requests.post(SearchUrl, headers=Header, json=json_data0)
print(response.status_code)

The error message I got is:
{'error': {'code': 'internal_error', 'message': 'Server Internal Error', 'log_id': 'A SERIES OF NUMBER AS THE LOG ID'}}

Following others' suggestions, I have simplified my request -- search for videos with hashtag "tiktok" in one day. But I still consistently got 500 errors.
jd_debug0 = {
'query': {
    'and': [
        {
            'operation': 'EQ',
            'field_name': 'hashtag_name',
            'field_values': ['tiktok'], 
        },
    ],
},
'max_count': 100,
'cursor': 0,
'start_date': "20231010",
'end_date': "20231010",

}

You need to post the code you tried in text form to your question so someone can take a look and see what is wrong with it, as a 500 error means something isn't configured correctly most likely.

Are you using any sort of front end or just doing simple POSTMAN requests?  And its sounding like its MAYBE hitting a timeout when it tries to get all the data and thus fails to send anything since the whole thing didn't make it.

Thanks! I just posted my code. I think I am just doing simple requests.

Also, I have kept my request pretty simple (only request for the same day, with only one keyword), but it is not working.

Good job on updating the post, I will add a suggestion to add the Pyton tag as that appears to be what you are using to interact with the JSON object.

I wonder if it has something to do with the fact the method you are using is 'POST' as in filling out a form versus a method 'GET' where you can get information returned through the URL?  As in you have request.post .. but you could do a url query to instead do request.get

Thanks! Based on TikTok API document, the HTTP method is "POST" instead of "GET". I also tried to use request.get but it returns 404.

As per the HTML response you got, the specific error message probably matters a lot; it would be helpful if you would post that.

Thanks, Andrew! I just posted the HTML response in the main text. I also past it here: {'error': {'code': 'internal_error', 'message': 'Server Internal Error', 'log_id': 'xxxx'}}. I cannot infer anything specific from this returned responses.

500 errors (not just on Tiktok) are difficult to handle precisely because the server has no more information about what went wrong; it basically means what you sent was so wrong that it didn't know how to show you a better error message. Some APIs are more accommodating than others but the only way to troubleshoot it really is to try something really simple and add back more complications until you find exactly which part of your complex query caused the error.

Thanks! @tripleee -- I have made my request as simple as possible (please see my updates above). But, it is still giving me error 500.
